# recurring period in sql script

Tags: sql, sql-server

The situation:

The user creates a case record that includes a date field (DateOpened), and wants to send the client a follow up every 30 days until the case is closed.
The user will run the query periodically (probably weekly) and provide a 'From' and 'To' date range to specify the period in which a record may fall within the mutliple of 30 days.

The request:

I need a method to identify records where the user specified date range includes those records which are a multiple of 30 days since the DateOpened date.

**UPDATE**
This is what came to me all of a sudden while watching a third rate TV show last night!!!

```
SELECT 
.... 
FROM 
....
WHERE
(CAST((DATEDIFF(dd, Invoice.DateOpened @EndDate)/30) AS INT) - CAST((DATEDIFF(dd, Invoice.DateOpened, @StartDate)/30) AS INT)) >=1 
OR DATEDIFF(dd, Invoice.DateOpened, @StartDate) % 30 = 0 --this line to capture valid records but where From and To dates are the same
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Sql Server, MySQL, Oracle, MS ACcess?

Answer (score 0):

Is this Microsoft SQL?  Is this Express edition?  As long as it's not Express, you may want to look into using the SQL Agent service, which lets you schedule tasks that can run against the database.  What do you want it to do with the record once it hits 30 days?

Comment: Thanks Adam, I am using a custom report utility that displays the records in a grid, and allows the user to specify criteria such as From and To dates and send the results to Excel. The user will need to run this function at their discretion. The 30 day multiple will need to fall within the user specified date range.

Comment: Adam, to answer your question...
I believe it is full SQL server (not express) that the user has, and so SQL Agent should be available. Your suggestion might be a possible solution if I use SQLCMD to perform the running of the SQL and also export the data as a csv file. I will investigate. Thanks Em

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DATEDIFF function to calculate the difference between dates in days.  You can use the modulus (%) operator to get the "remainder" of a division operation.  Combining the two gives you:

```
SELECT
    ....
FROM
    ....
WHERE
    --In MS T-SQL, BETWEEN is inclusive.
    DateOpened BETWEEN @UserSuppliedFromDate AND @UserSuppliedToDate
    AND DATEDIFF(dd, DateOpened, getdate()) % 30 = 0
```

which should give you the desired result.

Edit (Give this example a try in MSSQL):

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE
(
    ID integer,
    DateOpened datetime
)

DECLARE @FromDate as datetime = '1/1/2012'
DECLARE @ToDate as datetime = '12/31/2012'

INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (0, '1/1/1982')
INSERT INTO @Table values (1, '1/1/2012')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (2, '2/17/2012')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (3, '3/16/2012')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (4, '4/16/2012')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (5, '5/28/2012')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (6, '1/31/2012')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (7, '12/12/2013')

DECLARE @DateLoop as datetime
DECLARE @ResultIDs as table ( ID integer, DateLoopAtTheTime datetime, DaysDifference integer )

--Initialize to lowest possible value
SELECT @DateLoop = @FromDate

--Loop until we hit the maximum date to check
WHILE @DateLoop <= @ToDate
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @ResultIDs (ID,DateLoopAtTheTime, DaysDifference)
        SELECT ID, @DateLoop, DATEDIFF(dd,@DateLoop, DateOpened)
        FROM @Table 
        WHERE 
            DATEDIFF(dd,@DateLoop, DateOpened) % 30 = 0
            AND DATEDIFF(dd,@DateLoop,DateOpened) > 0 -- Avoids false positives when @DateLoop and DateOpened are the same
            AND DateOpened <= @ToDate
    SELECT @DateLoop = DATEADD(dd, 1, @DateLoop) -- Increment the iterator
END

SELECT distinct * From @ResultIDs
```

Comment: getdate() is MSSQL specific, apparently.  CURDATE() ought to work for MySQL.

Comment: Thanks Traxxus, I had also thought of using the MOD function but wasn't sure how to construct my statement to test against a range of dates entered by the user as 'From' and 'To' dates.

Comment: Thanks Traxxus. My fault for not being clear enough... The From and To dates are to specify the date range within which the 30 day multiple must fall. eg, if the user entered (From) 01/10/2012 and (To) 07/102012, we would need all records where a multiple of 30 days since the DateOpened falls within that date range.

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you mean.  Though there is almost certainly a better way to do it, you could iterate through the desired dates (a day at a time) using a WHILE loop, add the relevant records to a temporary table, then return the records contained within the temporary table as your result set.  I'll update the query in the morning, assuming someone doesn't beat me to it :)

Comment: Traxxus, Thanks for your time and response. Let me know if you can see any issues with my recently devised method I have added to my original question. Em